# c++ read a chunk from ifstream and write to ofstream

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to read a chunk of bytes from one `ifstream` then write to another `ofstream`.

here is my code:

```
size_t chunk_size = ...;
std::ifstream ifs(in_file_name);
std::ofstream ofs(out_file_name);

char * buffer = new char[chunk_size];
ifs.read(buffer, chunk_size);
ofs << buffer;
delete[] buffer;
```

is it the right way to do this?

According to CPP document, `std::ostream::operator<<` accept a `streambuffer *` as argument. I'm not sure whether a char array can be treated as a bufferstream.

(I can compile and run the code, but there is some problem in my program, I'm not sure if it's caused by this, still trying to figure it out...)

Comment: Why not just use `write`, to write the buffer?  A `char[]` is not a `streambuffer *`

Comment: You can  look at the documentation for `streambuf` and see if it's remotely related to a `char*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it the right way to do this?

Not quite so. If you use [`std::istream::read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) then most probably you should pair it with 
[`std::ostream::write()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) and it is better to use `std::vector<char>` for memory management (or at least smart pointer):

```
size_t chunk_size = ...;
std::ifstream ifs(in_file_name);
std::ofstream ofs(out_file_name);

{ // you can use block to limit lifetime of the vector
    std::vector<char> buffer( chunk_size );
    ifs.read( buffer.data(), buffer.size() );
    ofs.write( buffer.data(), buffer.size() ); 
}
```

problem with your code `std::ostream::operator<<` overload for `const char *` expects null terminated string, not binary data of fixed size

Comment: Strongly advise (a) testing the `read` call to ensure the stream is still valid, and (b) using [`std::istream::gcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) to determine just how much of `buffer` is actually valid afterward, and doing both before performing the `write` operation.